# Equivalent of “dupehammer” for review edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, edits, dupehammer

Stack Exchange has installed the "dupehammer" mechanism for a reason - at some point we trust a user and allow him/her to make decisions without second guessing him/her.

At 2,000 rep we trust a user so much that any edit he/she makes is instantly accepted.

However, if such a highly esteemed user is reviewing an edit (of someone else) and accepts it, this review is not instantaneously accepted - it need to wait for majority vote. Why?

Can't a 2,000 rep user have a "review hammer" and instantaneously accept/reject any review?
What difference does it make if he/she accepts/rejects suggested edit or make the same edit himself/herself?

**Update**

This proposal can be refined to edit reviews done from the Q&A page and not from the "review queue" to discourage "robo-reviewers".

Answer (score 9):

You do have some kind of hammer in the form of the 'Improve Edit' and 'Reject and Edit' options. Those let you singlehandedly decide the outcome of the review.

There are a couple of reasons for requiring two reviews: it's very easy just to click the Approve button without really paying attention to the edit itself. Some people do this deliberately (the so-called 'robo-reviewers'), and sometimes (especially after doing many reviews) reviewers are just paying a little less attention and miss a rather critical other thing that can be improved.

Comment: 1. With 2,000 reps I think we can give these users a bit of a credit they do not robo-review

Comment: *Most* of them do not robo-review, true. But those few that do, cause bad edits to trickle through the queues.

Comment: 2. My aim was actually not so much at the review queue, but rather on specific posts: I sometime answer a question and see it has a pending edit. I click it and approves/reject but instead of "hammering" the proposed edit - it goes back to the queue for additional reivewers - why?

Comment: If you still fear robo-reviewers one can add another privilege level at, say 5,000 rep, that allows for "review hammer".

Comment: Now *that* (hammering the edit from the Q&A page) would have some merit, and (AFAIK) has never been proposed before. (But please do search for it.)

Answer (score 6):

> What difference does it make if he/she accepts/rejects suggested edit
>   or make the same edit himself/herself?

I think the difference would be that in the latter the 2,000+ rep editor has their own name on it.

In the former the name of the inexperienced editor, who may be very inexperienced, is put on the edit, so it would be good for more than one reviewer to check their work.

Comment: It could be on the [review-tag-wiki-edits level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292) (5,000 reputation points) or [edit-tag-wikis-without-review level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292) (20,000 reputation points) (for simplicity).

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I think your proposal (question) would be better if your comment here were part of it.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** I think having an edit review hammer is not worth it, because:

- the *how* is hard to define
- it's not really broken, don't fix it. Dev time is better spent on other stuff

---

I'm surprised no one has yet brought up the fact that **dupehammers are earned through two metrics: quantity (200 answers) and quality (1000 score)**, and even then they are only given for a specific tag. This makes dupehammers quite hard to get, either because there's not enough questions to answer, not enough people to vote on them, or both.

**There are no such metrics for reviewing suggested edits**, because the quality of one's reviews is not reviewed, in turn, by their peers. Some sites have audit reviews enabled, but those don't aim to reward good behaviour; they're here to issue warnings/bans on bad behaviour. And as you can review anything, including stuff you may have 0 expertise on, this leaves the "specific tag" metric out as well.

Arguably a close vote dupehammer *should* be harder to obtain, as closing can be done rather silently (as informations on which questions recntly got closed is only easily available in the 10k tools overview), while edits get bumped on the homepage no matter what.

Still, it takes only two reviewers (three on SO) to approve/reject an edit, and as explained in the other answers, folks may review in a hurry. This works so far; perhaps less on smaller sites, but maybe we want even less of a one-person hammer on those.